# Next Auth - OAUTH_GET_ACCESS_TOKEN_ERROR

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to implement oauth in my next.js app. for backend I'm using [Django ODIC Provider](https://pypi.org/project/django-oidc-provider/) and [Next Auth](https://next-auth.js.org) for the front-end.

but I'm getting an error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "The provided authorization grant or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client"
}
```

How can I fix this ?

I have created a file named: `[...nextauth].js` in `/api/auth/` and added my custom provider.

Here's how my `env` looks like:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL = http://localhost:3000
CLIENT_ID = 466647
CLIENT_SECRET = 079e7fe518e245cb316701faa19ec463c0073fba25d1e51c2db996ab
SCOPES = openid profile email
```

and `[...nextauth].js`:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    {
      id: "pullstream",
      name: "Pullstream",
      type: "oauth",
      version: "2.0",
      scope: process.env.SCOPES,
      params: { grant_type: "authorization_code" },
      accessTokenUrl: "https://accounts.dev.pullstream.com/api/openid/token/",
      requestTokenUrl: "https://accounts.dev.pullstream.com/api/accounts/login/",
      authorizationUrl: "https://accounts.dev.pullstream.com/api/openid/authorize/",
      profileUrl: "https://accounts.dev.pullstream.com/api/accounts/profile/",
      async profile(profile, tokens) {
        console.log(profile, tokens)
      },
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
    }
  ],
})
```

Comment: I have already tried changing Client Type from `confidential` to `public` but it didn't work

Comment: hey, did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callbacks` config of `[...nextauth].js` to get `access_token`.

```js
...
callbacks: {
  /**
   * @param  {object}  token     Decrypted JSON Web Token
   * @param  {object}  user      User object      (only available on sign in)
   * @param  {object}  account   Provider account (only available on sign in)
   * @param  {object}  profile   Provider profile (only available on sign in)
   * @param  {boolean} isNewUser True if new user (only available on sign in)
   * @return {object}            JSON Web Token that will be saved
   */
  async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
    // Add access_token to the token right after signin
    if (account?.accessToken) {
      token.accessToken = account.accessToken
    }
    return token
  }
}
...
```

> The contents user, account, profile and isNewUser will vary depending on the provider and on if you are using a database or not. If you want to pass data such as User ID, OAuth Access Token, etc. to the browser, you can persist it in the token and use the `session()` callback to return it.

Source:[JWT callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) [Session callback](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback)